# Android database issue managing date

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a table in sqlite database that is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

When I insert data in this table, the date field is automatically set.

When I try to retrieve the content of the inserted row.

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("created_at")));
```

where c is the Cursor.

The date I retrieve is 1 hour behind the correct date. Consider that I'm in Italy (UTC+1.00)

How can I obtain the correct date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) will record the current time in UTC time zone.

Use e.g. [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) if you want to format your datetime stamps to other timezones.

Comment: Are you saying that I should use SimpleDateFormat when I retrieve the Date?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider Day Light Saving time.. This may be the problem as DST is there.. That can be the difference of time.

```
CREATE TABLE whatever(
     ....
     timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
     ...
);
```

Comment: My database is Sqlite

Comment: what is the timezone of your device or simulator ?

Comment: I have also tried that solution. But the result is the same.